# ATFSDC010 SD host controller can communicatio with eMMC?

Tags: sd-card, sdmmc

I'm trying to read eMMC data with sd host controller.

sd host controller : ATFSDC010
eMMC               : KLM8G1GESD-B04P
eMMC Reader        : EMMC MODULE READER FOR ODROID

First, i have initialized eMMC as transfer state (CMD0->CMD1->CMD2->CMD3->CMD7)

Second, i have sent CMD18(READ_MULTI_BLOCK)

if i send CMD18, sd host controller starts clock toggling and read data from eMMC with rising edge(sd host controller's FIFO is only 64byte, so it stops clock toggling after read 64byte)

when i read 64byte of first FIFO, it's not courrupted

if FIFO become empty, sd host controller restarts clock toggling to read 64byte

when i read 64byte of second FIFO, only first bit of data is always inverted(ex: 0x4a -> 0xca) and third FIFO, fourth FIFO ... is same

below is first FIFO read signal (data is 0x4a)
[image]

below is fourth FIFO read signal (data should be 0x7a but 0xfa)
it's weird that i have received 0xfa, but signal is 0xf4 or 0xea
[image]

I think SD and eMMC's read timing is different.
below is read timing of (1)SD card, (2)eMMC
[image]
[image]

am i right? if i misunderstood, please let me know about that..

I'm still a beginner. I ask of your understanding.

Comment: Hey! From the looks of it I think your question is more fit for the [electronics version of stackoverflow](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: Oh! i didn’t know about that. thank you!  :)